# cant display a value saved in cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

i am trying to display an alert called says welcome user and this user i entered 
here is my code

```js
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First Page A1 </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="text.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "game.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body >
        
        <div  id="container">
   <h1>
      Khokha Game
    </h1>
      <div id="formContent">
    <form id="myform" action="game.html"  method="get" >
     <table>
      <tr>
                               <td>Your Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username"></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
                                <td>Difficulty</td>
        <td>
        <select id="difficulty" name="difficylty">
         <option value="1">Easy</option>
                                   <option value="2">Medium</option>
                                   <option value="3">Difficult</option>
                           
        </select></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Start" onclick="checkCookie()"></td>
      </tr>
            
     </table>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>
 
<script>


function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return " ";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = document.getElementById("username");
    //alert(user);
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 1);
       }
    }
}

</script>  
</html>
```

but what happens is that the cookie doesnot store the value of user and i donot know why .. any help ??
i cant get it well

Comment: I would suggest use of localStorage

Comment: How about changing return " "; to **return "";** and user = document.getElementById("username"); to **user = document.getElementById("username").value;**?